# .Htaccess Block Direct access php file

Tags: .htaccess

i have a some php files that i dont want someone to view on iframe and to access directly so i made a code that block other sites to view in iframe and just my site can iframe those php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.html [L,QSA]
```

so here just example.com can view those php files on iframe  (this works)
but How i can blocks users to view php files directly?